# How to change the most significant bit to a 1 after shifting an int to the right using '>>'?

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

For example, when I have a number such as 0x54 in binary that would be 01010100. After using the bit-wise operator '>>' this number will turn into 00101010. Instead of the most significant bit being a 0, I need it to be a one. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: What other binary operators do you know?

Comment: Note that `>>` takes *two* operands. In your example, you've apparently written `0x54 >> 1`. Will you always be writing `>> 1`, or will you sometimes shift by more than one? If the latter, then -- what behavior do you need in that case?

Comment: Also, in your example you show eight bits. Is it fair to assume that you're using the `byte` type, such that the most significant bit will always be the bit at 0x80?

Comment: `(x >> 1) | (1 << 31)` for an int.

Comment: @BeauVansiclen: Re: "a long that comprises of 32 bits": But you've tagged this question as [java], and in Java a `long` is always 64 bits. (Its 32-bit counterpart is `int`.)

Comment: (Also, when a comment points out that your question is missing information, you should add that information to the question. It's great to reply *as well*, but that's not a substitute for editing the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your number always 8 bits wide? If thats the case you can simply have the decimal representation of 10000000 which is 128 and do a bitwise or
so let's take your example

```
int val = 84; /// 01010100
int newVal = val >> 1; // 00101010
int mostSig = newVal | 128; // 10101010
```

Comment: The question states shifting an int but if it's a long value then it's more or less the same approach.

```long maxLongVal = 1L << 31; // 100000000000....
long val = 84;
long newVal = val >> 1;
long mostSig = newVal | maxLongVal; // 100000.....0101010```